# Finding, substituting and executing values in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, closure

I wrote this code for finding, substituting and executing values in dictionary, much like `$()` bash operator works.

I used nested functions for this, forming hierarchy and encapsulating their names.
But now I'm concern, that this may be an overhead in reading ease and unit testing now
sucks, because I can't write test for concrete nested function in other file.

Should I make this functions global, or this approach is acceptable?

```py
def execute_steps(config):
    def search_for_expand(var_name, stage_name):
        if var_name in config.typedef.evaluators:
            return config.typedef.evaluators[var_name]
        if var_name in config.typedef.stages[stage_name]:
            return config.typedef.stages[stage_name][var_name]
        for stage in config.typedef.stages:
            if var_name in config.typedef.stages[stage]:
                return config.typedef.stages[stage][var_name]
        return var_name

    def execute_abstract(stage_name):
        def substitute_macroses(var_name):
            def is_expandable(value):
                return DEF.EXECUTOR in value

            def expand(var_value):
                for match in DEF.EXECUTOR_RE.finditer(var_value):
                    value_to_expand = match.group(1)
                    var_value = var_value.replace(match.group(0),
                                                  search_for_expand(value_to_expand,
                                                  stage_name))
                return var_value

            var_value = stage[var_name]
            if is_expandable(var_value):
                stage[var_name] = expand(var_value)

        stage = config.typedef.stages[stage_name]
        for k in stage:
            substitute_macroses(k)

    def execute_build(stage):
        execute_abstract(DEF.BUILD)
        out = subprocess.run(stage[config.build_process.result],
                            shell=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        return out

    def execute_static(stage, build_out):
        execute_abstract(DEF.STATIC)
        out = subprocess.run(stage[config.static_process.result],
                            shell=True,
                            input=build_out.stdout,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        return out

    def execute_dynamic(stage, static_out):
        execute_abstract(DEF.DYNAMIC)
        out = subprocess.run(stage[config.dynamic_process.result],
                            shell=True,
                            input=static_out.stdout,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        return out


    build_out = execute_build(config.typedef.stages[DEF.BUILD])
    static_out = execute_static(config.typedef.stages[DEF.STATIC], build_out)
    dynamic_out = execute_dynamic(config.typedef.stages[DEF.DYNAMIC], static_out)

    return (build_out, static_out, dynamic_out)
```